# How to insert a string into an sql server table via a windows form?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have an sql server table located on my website (remote). The table is called `table1` and it has 1 field called `f1`. My goal here is to insert the string "hello there" into it with a C# method with the signature as follows:

```
AddTof1(string s) 
{

}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people can show their. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: You need to put more time and effort into your question if you want an an answerer to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AddTof1(string s) 
{    
  using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
  {
      connection.Open();

      using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO table1 values(@s)", connection))
      {
          command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s", s);
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
  }

}
```

Then you can call this method as;

```
AddTof1("hello there");
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't need the logon bit because that's done elsewhere in my program. 

What does the "@" character do? Is it required?

Comment: @John `@` character using for matching the parameter in your query. In this case, your `@s` parameter in your query is matching with your `s` variable which is getting in parameter in your method.

Comment: @John thanks. I think you were downvoted because you stooped to answering my noob question lol. Thanks anyway.